# jQuery mobile: data-search value returns empty unless I reload the page

Tags: ajax, jquery-mobile, input, filter

*jQuery Mobile 1.3.2:* I have a `listview` with the filter enabled. The page that this is on is loaded via jQuery mobile ajax.

My problem is that if I allow it to load via ajax, it detects my `keyup` event but it does not pull the value of `input[data-type="search"]`. If I refresh the page using the browser, the script executes perfectly.

How can I get this to work while loading the page with AJAX?

HTML MARKUP:

```
 <ul id="addCompany" style="padding-bottom:10px;" data-role="listview" >
    <li><a href="#" onclick="$( 'input[data-type="search"]' ).focus()">Touch To Add</a></li>
 </ul>
 <div id="listwrap">
<ul data-role="listview" data-autodividers="true" data-filter="true" data-inset="true">
<li><a href="index.html">Adam Kinkaid</a></li>
 </ul>
 </div>
```

jQuery

```
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var inputVal;
                $('body').on("keyup",'input[data-type="search"]', function(){
                    inputVal = $('input[data-type="search"]').val();
                    if(inputVal===""){
                        $('#dynamic').html('<li><a href="#" onclick="$( \'form input\' ).focus()">Touch To Add</a></li>');
                        $('#dynamic').listview("refresh");
                    }else{
                        $('#dynamic').html('<li><a href="next.php?i&newitem='+encodeURIComponent($('input[data-type="search"]').val())+'">Touch Again To Add: '+$('input[data-type="search"]').val()+'</a></li>');
                        $('#dynamic').listview("refresh");
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
```

**EDIT**: Note that I can set the value and set the focus on `input[data-type="search"]` without any hiccups. It is retrieving the value that seems so tricky.

I tried adding a class to so that I wouldn't have to call it by data attribute but still couldn't pull the value unless I refreshed the page. Maybe if I inject a function into the input element I can use that to return the value?

Comment: Post your html markup.

Comment: Omar, please see my revisions in the original post.

Comment: It seems that it maybe just isn't getting the most recent version (value in this case) of the input field. As if multiple have been created. I don't know if jQuery creates and deletes this field or not.

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/N5Knk/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Your solution only works if I don't load the page via ajax - the same problem that I am currently having with my script.